# Transcendence measure

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

Let $a\in\mathbb C$. Suppose that for all $k\in\mathbb N$ ($k>1$), there exist $U_k>0, V_k>0$ such that for every $n\in\mathbb N$, there exists a polynomial $P_n\in\mathbb Z[X]$ with degree $k$,
$$
P_n(X)=\sum_{l=0}^ka_{k,l,n}X^l,
$$
such that
$$
0<|P_n(a)|\le\dfrac{(V_k|a|)^{nk}}{n^{kn}} 
$$ and
$$|a_{k,l,n}|\le U^{nk}_kn^n\quad\forall l\in[0,k].
$$ Liouville inequality shows that $a$ is transcendental. But can one determine a transcendence measure of $a$?

Comment: Obviously that information is not enough to find a transcendence measure, but you can estimate it.You can use that $P_n(a)^m$ is small for any positive integer $m$.

Comment: @Oleg Can you elaborate a little bit more, please?

Comment: You have $0<|P(a)|^m\leq\frac{1}{n^{knm}}$. Estimate coefficients of $P(x)^m$ roughly by $(k+1)^mn^{nm}$ and you have estimates for transcendence measure.